# How to create an Iteratee that passes through values to an inner Iteratee unless a specific value is found

Tags: scala, playframework, loops

I've got an ADT that's essentially a cross between `Option` and `Try`:

```
sealed trait Result[+T]
case object Empty extends Result[Nothing]
case class Error(cause: Throwable) extends Result[Nothing]
case class Success[T](value: T) extends Result[T]
```

(assume common combinators like `map`, `flatMap` etc are defined on Result)

Given an `Iteratee[A, Result[B]` called `inner`, I want to create a new `Iteratee[Result[A], Result[B]]` with the following behavior:

- If the input is a `Success(a)`, feed `a` to `inner`
- If the input is an `Empty`, no-op
- If the input is an `Error(err)`, I want `inner` to be completely ignored, instead returning a `Done` iteratee with the `Error(err)` as its result.

Example Behavior:

```
// inner: Iteratee[Int, Result[List[Int]]]
// inputs:
1
2
3
// output:
Success(List(1,2,3))

// wrapForResultInput(inner): Iteratee[Result[Int], Result[List[Int]]]
// inputs:
Success(1)
Success(2)
Error(Exception("uh oh"))
Success(3)

// output:
Error(Exception("uh oh"))
```

This sounds to me like the job for an `Enumeratee`, but I haven't been able to find anything in [the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumeratee$) that looks like it'll do what I want, and the internal implementations are still voodoo to me.

How can I implement `wrapForResultInput` to create the behavior described above?

---

Adding some more detail that won't really fit in a comment:

Yes it looks like I was mistaken in my question. I described it in terms of `Iteratees` but it seems I really am looking for `Enumeratees`.

At a certain point in the API I'm building, there's a `Transformer[A]` class that is essentially an `Enumeratee[Event, Result[A]]`. I'd like to allow clients to transform that object by providing an `Enumeratee[Result[A], Result[B]]`, which would result in a `Transformer[B]` aka an `Enumeratee[Event, Result[B]]`.

For a more complex example, suppose I have a `Transformer[AorB]` and want to turn that into a `Transformer[(A, List[B])]`:

```
// the Transformer[AorB] would give
a, b, a, b, b, b, a, a, b

// but the client wants to have
a -> List(b),
a -> List(b, b, b),
a -> Nil
a -> List(b)
```

The client could implement an `Enumeratee[AorB, Result[(A, List[B])]]` without too much trouble using `Enumeratee.grouped`, but they are required to provide an `Enumeratee[Result[AorB], Result[(A, List[B])]` which seems to introduce a lot of complication that I'd like to hide from them if possible.

```
val easyClientEnumeratee = Enumeratee.grouped[AorB]{
  for {
    _ <- Enumeratee.dropWhile(_ != a) ><> Iteratee.ignore
    headResult <- Iteratee.head.map{ Result.fromOption }
    bs <- Enumeratee.takeWhile(_ == b) ><> Iteratee.getChunks
} yield headResult.map{_ -> bs}

val harderEnumeratee = ??? ><> easyClientEnumeratee

val oldTransformer: Transformer[AorB] = ... // assume it already exists
val newTransformer: Transformer[(A, List[B])] = oldTransformer.andThen(harderEnumeratee)
```

So what I'm looking for is the `???` to define the `harderEnumeratee` in order to ease the burden on the user who already implemented `easyClientEnumeratee`.

I guess the `???` should be an `Enumeratee[Result[AorB], AorB]`, but if I try something like

```
Enumeratee.collect[Result[AorB]] {
  case Success(ab) => ab
  case Error(err) => throw err
}
```

the error will actually be thrown; I actually want the error to come back out as an `Error(err)`.

Comment: Oh, I've just realized. You want Iteratee to complete as soon as Error occures....

Answer (score 1):

Simplest implementation of such would be `Iteratee.fold2` method, that could collect elements until something is happened.

Since you return single result and can't really return anything until you verify there is no errors, `Iteratee` would be enough for such a task

```
def listResults[E] = Iteratee.fold2[Result[E], Either[Throwable, List[E]]](Right(Nil)) { (state, elem) =>
  val Right(list) = state
  val next = elem match {
    case Empty => (Right(list), false)
    case Success(x) => (Right(x :: list), false)
    case Error(t) => (Left(t), true)
  }
  Future(next)
} map {
  case Right(list) => Success(list.reverse)
  case Left(th) => Error(th)
}
```

Now if we'll prepare little playground

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val good = Enumerator.enumerate[Result[Int]](
  Seq(Success(1), Empty, Success(2), Success(3)))

val bad = Enumerator.enumerate[Result[Int]](
  Seq(Success(1), Success(2), Error(new Exception("uh oh")), Success(3)))

def runRes[X](e: Enumerator[Result[X]]) : Result[List[X]] = Await.result(e.run(listResults), 3 seconds)
```

we can verify those results

```
runRes(good) //res0: Result[List[Int]] = Success(List(1, 2, 3))
runRes(bad) //res1: Result[List[Int]] = Error(java.lang.Exception: uh oh)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is helpful, though not exactly what I am asking for. I'm looking to create a function/enumeratee/whatever that can be applyed to *any* `inner: Iteratee[A, Result[B]]`. The intended usage is in a library where clients would implement `inner`, and I am hoping to hide the added complexity of handling success/error by providing this function. The simple example I provided was only an example of one such `inner`. I will be sure to mention the `fold2` approach in my documentation. That said, is the generalized function/enumeratee doable?

Comment: @Dylan `Iteratee[A, Result[B]]` is a producer of single `Result[B]` from stream of `A` elements. Are you sure, it's intended design?

Comment: What I wanted to say won't fit in a comment, so I've added more detail to the question. See my edits above. I think what I'm looking for is actually an `Enumeratee[Result[A], A]` but a simple `Collect` won't cut it for the behavior I was looking for.